# Why arguments is given ...arguments in the arguments place like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My point is this:

```
function sum(...arguments) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        const [firstArg] = arguments;
        if (firstArg instanceof Array) {
            return sum(...firstArg)
        }
    }
return arguments.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

What is this ... are doing infront of arguments. And also please help me know that why const [firstArg] is given and how this is working. And please explain me instanceof in easy words. My native language is not english. Thank you so much.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/07/how-to-use-arguments-and-parameters-in-ecmascript-6/

Comment: [JavaScript spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you @ServeshChaturvedi for your idea of double quotes. I hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to help. @UsmanKhan

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi The biggest problem I face is that whenever I search on google about technical things, its meaning is really difficult like my native language is not English. That's why I have to go through hard time and I'm still struggling in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [`rest syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

> The rest parameter syntax allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array.

This:

```
const [firstArg] = arguments;
```

is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> [it] makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

Re `instanceOf`:

> [The instanceof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) tests to see if the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object. The return value is a boolean value.

Unpacking this code:

```js
function sum(...arguments) {

  // arguments is an array thanks
  // to the rest syntax. If it has a length of
  // one...
  if (arguments.length === 1) {

    // Get the first element
    const [firstArg] = arguments;

    // If that element is an array
    if (firstArg instanceof Array) {

      // Call sum again with that element
      return sum(...firstArg)
    }
  }

  // Return the sum of the arguments
  return arguments.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

Your function could be easily simplified by [`flattening`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the arguments, and then using `reduce` to return the sum. And this way you can even have a set of single values passed in, or *n* multiple arrays as a single argument to the function, or a mixture of both.

```js
function sum(...args) {
  return args.flat().reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0);
}

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));
console.log(sum([1], 1, 2, 3));
console.log(sum([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(sum([1, 2], [1, 4, 3]));
console.log(sum([1, 2], [12, 20], [1, 4, 3]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andy. It really helped.

Answer (score 2):

(...arguments) is the rest parameter syntax and allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array, providing a way to represent variadic functions in JavaScript.
for more information, you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```
const [firstArg] = arguments;
```

is something named Destructuring assignment
The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

you can read more, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

and in the last, The instanceof operator tests to see if the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object. The return value is a boolean value

Answer (score 0):

This because ...  is a javascript  tool that allows you to put multiple parameters  in a function it is called the rest parameter function.

Comment: John can you really make this easy for me that how this function is working on each line and making decision.